# Redirect to referrer, confirm_form

Tags: 7, forms

I have few `confirm_forms` which could be invoked from different places. I would like to redirect user to proper place after cancelation. `Referrer` Header is not good way to do it so I'm looking for good idea to do it in drupal. Maybe something with `current_path`?

Menu for deletion is defined like so:

```
$menu['module/entity/%/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete directory',
    'description' => 'Remove directory from ITC Backup',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('module_entity_delete_form', 2),
    'access arguments' => array('Entity administer'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
);
```

Form creation function is (at the moment) defined this way:

```
function module_entity_delete_form($form, &$form_state, $did) {
    $form['Id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $did
    );

    return confirm_form($form, t('Are you sure you want to delete selected entity?'), 'module/entity/list');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered yourself :).  If you want to redirect back to the page the user invoked it from, set `$path` to `current_path()` when calling `confirm_form`.  Otherwise set `$path` to wherever you want them to go on cancel.

Comment: I'm using `drupal_get_form` in `hook_menu` for each `confirm_form` so `current_path` there will be just looping back to `confirm_form`

Comment: Calling `confirm_form` directly in `hook_menu` is kind of strange.  What's you use case for this?

Comment: Sorry I misread that, it's early here!  Why would `current_path` loop back to the confirm_form if you're calling it in the form builder?  One would think it would return to the initial form.

Comment: `confirm_form` is not called directly in hook_menu. I added some simple code to my question. It works great if invoked from one place and if it is part of just one 'storyline'.

Comment: Ok that helps, so you're deleting something.  By "proper place after cancelation" do you mean after form submission when the entity is removed?  I took that to mean where they are redirected when they hit the cancel button.  If the former, you can either set `$form_state['redirect']` in your submission handler and/or include the `destination` GET param if building a link.  Either way please clarify and also mention what the proper place is and I'll update answer.

Comment: Unrelated but you may want to change `'Id'` to the `value` type if you're not using it for JS.  With operations affecting the database, `hidden` is a bit insecure as the user could potentially modify the value in the source.  `value` on the other hand will persist but is not accessible.

Comment: after deletion user is redirected to list of entities and it is only place. But after clicking 'Cancel' user should be redirected to place from deletion confirmation was invoked, which is entity page or entities list. Hmm, `destination` param could do in deletion link from entities list.

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to add a custom param like '?cancel=x' and have some logic to figure out what to put in `$path`.